# Minimize CentOS-based Docker image

Tags: php, docker, centos

I built a PHP-FPM image based on CentOS image

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
    yum -y install php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-mbstring php-intl php-amqp php-redis php-opcache --enablerepo remi,remi-php56 && \
    groupadd -g 1000 nginx && \
    useradd -u 1000 -g 1000 nginx

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
```

and realized that the final image's quite big (over 350MB). Please tell me where I can remove unwanted files as some Debian-based image on Docker Hub?

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clean up yums cache with `yum clean all` like this:

```
RUN yum -y install http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
    yum -y install php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-mbstring php-intl php-amqp php-redis php-opcache --enablerepo remi,remi-php56 && \
    groupadd -g 1000 nginx && \
    useradd -u 1000 -g 1000 nginx && \
    yum clean all
```

This saves about 70 MB.

If thats not enough, you could consider using a different base image like  **BusyBox** or **Alpine**.

Centos already has about 170 MB

Comment: Thank you! `yum clean all` reduces the image size from 350MB to 280MB. And is there any `log` or `temporary` directory we can remove to save anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the SCL packages (php56-php*) in "remi-safe" repository (and use the /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm command).

While the php-* packages provides both NTS and ZTS (thread safe) build, php56-php-* packages only provides the standard NTS build (and the ZTS build is not needed in your case) so are smaller.

Don't really know how much you will save.